# How to use sed command to add a string before a pattern string?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to use sed to modify my file named "baz".

When i search a pattern foo , foo is not at the beginning or end of line, i want to append bar before foo, how can i do it using sed?

```
Input file named baz:
blah_foo_blahblahblah
blah_foo_blahblahblah
blah_foo_blahblahblah
blah_foo_blahblahblah

Output file 
blah_barfoo_blahblahblah
blah_barfoo_blahblahblah
blah_barfoo_blahblahblah
blah_barfoo_blahblahblah
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just use something like:

```
sed 's/foo/barfoo/g' baz
```

(the `g` at the end means global, every occurrence on each line rather than just the first).

For an *arbitrary* (rather than fixed) pattern such as `foo[0-9]`, you could use capture groups as follows:

```
pax$ echo 'xyz fooA abc
xyz foo5 abc
xyz fooB abc' | sed 's/\(foo[0-9]\)/bar\1/g'

xyz fooA abc
xyz barfoo5 abc
xyz fooB abc
```

The parentheses capture the actual text that matched the pattern and the `\1` uses it in the substitution.

You can use arbitrarily complex patterns with this one, including ensuring you match only complete words. For example, only changing the pattern if it's immediately surrounded by a word boundary:

```
pax$ echo 'xyz fooA abc
xyz foo5 abc foo77 qqq xfoo4 zzz
xyz fooB abc' | sed 's/\(\bfoo[0-9]\b\)/bar\1/g'

xyz fooA abc
xyz barfoo5 abc foo77 qqq xfoo4 zzz
xyz fooB abc
```

---

In terms of how the capture groups work, you can use parentheses to store the text that matches a pattern for later use in the replacement. The captured identifiers are based on the `(` characters reading from left to right, so the regex (I've left off the `\` escape characters and padded it a bit for clarity):

```
( ( \S* )   ( \S* ) )
^ ^     ^   ^     ^ ^
| |     |   |     | |
| +--2--+   +--3--+ |
+---------1---------+
```

when applied to the text `Pax Diablo` would give you three groups:

```
\1 = Pax Diablo
\2 = Pax
\3 = Diablo
```

as shown below:

```
pax$ echo 'Pax Diablo' | sed 's/\(\(\S*\) \(\S*\)\)/[\1] [\2] [\3]/'
[Pax Diablo] [Pax] [Diablo]
```

Comment: actually i want to append a string before a matching pattern, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Or even `sed 's/^foo/bar&/'`.

Comment: well, foo is not appeared in the beginning or end of line

Comment: @Kit, I've added some other options, in terms of increasing complexity. The most adaptable one is probably the last, with capture groups.

Comment: ya! that's what i found. Could you mind explain more what does \1 means and the use of ()? what do u mean capture the actual text? I can't find the meaning of \1 in the man pages :(

Comment: The `man` pages aren't always that comprehensive. You're better off getting a dead-tree description (book) or using `info sed` for more detail. I'll also update my answer with some more meat.

Answer (score 3):

Just **substitute** the start of the line with something different.

```
sed '/^foo/s/^/bar/'
```

Comment: the "s" is to add string before the matching pattern?

Comment: No. It's to **substitute** the pattern with the replacement. The pattern happens to be the beginning of the line.

Comment: what about foo is not the the beginning of the line?

Comment: That's the search pattern. The `s` operator has its operands specified after it.

Answer (score 0):

To replace or modify all "foo" except at beginning or end of line, I would suggest to temporarily replace them at beginning and end of line with a unique sentinel value.

```
sed 's/^foo/____veryunlikelytoken_bol____/
  s/foo$/____veryunlikelytoken_eol____/
  s/foo/bar&/g
  s/^____veryunlikelytoken_bol____/foo/
  s/____veryunlikelytoken_eol____$/foo/'
```

In `sed` there is no way to specify "cannot match here".  In Perl regex and derivatives (meaning languages which borrowed from Perl's regex, not necessarily languages derived from Perl) you have various negative assertions so you can do something like

```
perl -pe 's/(?!^)foo(?!$)/barfoo/g'
```