# How to add some string before a particular type of words?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sed

I have a file, whose contents are :-

```
abc"/wiki/A"def
ghi"/wiki/B"jkl
mno"/wiki/C"pqr
```

And I want to add "**https://en.wikipedia.org**" before all **/wiki/** in the given sentences.
There can be many more these types of string in the file.

Required results are :-

```
abc"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A"def
ghi"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B"jkl
mno"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C"pqr
```

**I tried some solutions which are :-**

[How to use sed command to add a string before a pattern string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619917/how-to-use-sed-command-to-add-a-string-before-a-pattern-string)

[Insert text before a certain line using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248784/insert-text-before-a-certain-line-using-bash)

**as per my guess, it is related to "/" character before "wiki". Ignoring "/" it is working perfectly.**

**provided solution by me is :-**

```
sed 's//wiki//bar/wiki//g' abcdef
```

**but shown errors is**

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Duplicate of [sed fails with "unknown option to \`s'" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-fails-with-unknown-option-to-s-error)

Comment: Thank you for your concern @WiktorStribiżew i thought thatit was different question, bcz in that question 's' is there and in mine it's '-e'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add \ (back slash) before / (slash) to identification different meaning / in sed.

If you running on terminal necessary -e option to executed. This is manual sed.

-e CMD  Add CMD to sed commands to be executed

```
sed -e 's/wiki/https\:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki/g'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; But it is not working, I am getting "/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A" instead of "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A"; such that extra / (slash) before http....... .

Comment: you just need add "\" before your "/".

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:-

```
sed 's/\/wiki/https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki/g' filename
```